# SystemVerilog bind assertion sequence with variable

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have to write a SystemVerilog assertion with binding.

The assertion should be something like:

```
assert property (@(posedge (mod_clk & clk_gen_enable)) ##delay (clk_sync == 1));
```

`mod_clk`, `clk_gen_en` and `clk_sync` are signals of the module which I `bind` to, and `delay` is a variable which is a result of a calculation and should be in "units" of `st_clk`, which is also signal of the module which I `bind` to.

How can I write it correctly?

Comment: There many things which are not clear here. For example, how do you bind and into what. What makes you think that the code you provided is not correct? Are you getting errors, wrong behavior? Please provide an example which could be reproduced and refine your question to a particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bind to work, all you need is encapsulate this assertion in a module

```
module my_module;
assert property (@(posedge (mod_clk & clk_gen_enable)) ##delay (clk_sync == 1));
endmodule
```

Then use the `bind` construct to insert `my_module` into your target module. Verilog search rules will search upwards to find your signal names.

```
bind my_target_module my_module my_instance_name();
```

`##delay` works on the clock edge you specified before it which you have as `mod_clk & clk_gen_enable`. I'm guessing you really mean to have `clk_gen_enable` as an implication.

```
property sync;
  int counter;
  @(posedge mod_clk) (clk_gen_enable, counter=delay)
        |-> @(posedge st_clk) (1,counter--)[*0:$] ##1 counter<0 ##0 (clk_sync == 1));
endproperty
```

Comment: @dave_59- That's what I meant. But can I use a variable in the number of cycles? It may change once in a while....

Comment: Sorry, missed that requirement in my answer. See edited answer

Comment: can you explain the second part `(1,counter--)[*0:$] ##1 counter<0 ##0 (clk_sync == 1))`. Regarding the `clk_gen_enable`  - it's mean is not implication, I have to check the `clk_sync` x delay after once I recognize a posedge of `mod_clk` while `clk_gen_en == 1`

Comment: SystemVerilog assertions work similar to text regular expressions. `[*0:$]` means the previous expression `1` has to be true between 0 and an infinite number of consecutive cycles. The *next* cycle, `counter` must be negative. When that matches, in the *same*, `clk_sync` must be true.

Comment: it's not working correctly. I can see in the waves that the assertion is active since the negedge of the `mod_clk`, and finished one clock of `st_clk` after the negedge of `clk_sync` in case `clk_sync == 0` (and it passed' though it should failed). In case  `clk_sync == 0` the assertion is active since the posedge of the `mod_clk`, and finished on the negedge of `clk_sync`.